14amp 240V induction cooktop instructions call for 40/240 breaker?
The 2 burner induction cooktop has a 20 Amp plug and the input wire is labeled as 16 Amp and stamped 14awgx3c 300v. Here is the amazon item page link:
https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01MZWMEF3/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1
K&H 2 burner induction cooktop; 240V 3100W model INDH-3102Hx
home-and-kitchen.com is seller's website. Bottom sticker says device conforms to UL std. 1026; certified to CSA std c22.2 no. 64
Made in china but the parent company of K&H is german.
Also says Intertek 5002920 on bottom.
I had purchased a double 20 Amp circuit breaker and 20 Amp wire but seller's install instructions say double 40 Amp 240 breaker needed. Seller's explanation: It's a double breaker for 240V 2x20A.
I have communicated with the seller's tech person about 6 times and they insist that a 40 amp double breaker is required because device needs 20 amps on each pole which adds up to 40 amps. They insist I am wrong.
I reported to amazon that this item breaks either NA wiring codes (input wire rating and plug insufficient for 40 amps) or has incorrect installation instructions. Pointed out that this isn't safe and Amazon is looking into it.
Amazon returned my purchase price so I can toss the thing if no one can figure out how to wire it. I asked people who had purchased item if anyone had used 20 amp double breaker. One person says yes and it works fine.
Sorry I didn't include item info initially because I never expected anyone to try to look at it! I figured y'all would explain to me how the seller was right and why I was wrong. I have a masters in EE but more digitally oriented.
If I use 20 Amp stuff, I have read that it is OK to connect two separate 20 Amp wires between the 240 breaker and receptacle or do I need a single 4 wire 12 gauge wire? More wires anyhow.


Thanks for the instructions. Slightly different model number but perhaps what they are welling  now under my model number. So much better than the one page piece of crap they sent me!!!

Contact the seller/maker.  One of those statements is wrong and would trust the makers instructions more than amazon.  Wire size is related to breaker size.  Most breakers will have minimum wire gauge that can be placed on them.  20 amp wire size on 20 amp breaker.  Wire size can be larger, but never smaller, except for wires attached by the maker/manufacturer.

Seems to me that the breaker requirement got mis-translated in the seller's marketing material. A double 220V x 20A breaker is not a 40A breaker - it's still a 20A breaker. But with that kind of error in the installation instructions I have to wonder if this cooktop is UL (or other NRTL) listed and approved for use in the USA  since the installation instructions are part of the listing ...

Links to both the Amazon listing and the manufacturer's product page would be helpful. You don't even mention the make or model here. Please revise your post to add detail, and take the [tour].

What's the model of the unit?

If it's off Amazon, I'm sure it's Chinese.  Is the unit UL Listed?  How about CSA or ETL?  Can't install it here otherwise, see NEC 110.2.  If it is really German, Germans get 230/400V 3-phase (3 legs of 230V), but there should be instructions and specs for a single-phase installation.

Can you post photos of the bottom sticker on the device you have please?

Given that its on its own circuit, your 20A breaker will work
Based on the nameplate rating of 3100W, this unit pulls 13A@240V.  As a result, while this unit could be wired using a 15A breaker even, your 20A breaker and wire are fine, as the load for a single cooktop or oven unit is the nameplate load, as per Note 5 to Table 220.55 in the NEC.

Did you get installation instructions the same as online?
Page 7 Note 4 says:

A 3-wire single phase 240 or 208 Volt, 60 Hz AC only electrical supply
is required, on a separate circuit fused on both sides of the line (a
20A time-delay fuse or circuit breaker is recommended)

A 2-pole 20A breaker is correct.

And the diagram in the instructions shows the white neutral wire from the power supply connected to the ground screw of the junction box. Maybe the appliance itself is listed by ETL, but the instructions are all confused.

I attached what I received from them and it is all I ever got from them. So do I attach neutral to ground in the circuit panel or just clip it? The wire from cooktop is wired to the plug neutral and they say to ground it.

I didn't examine the diagram. That diagram could only be legal where you have an existing  pre 1996 3 wire range circuit. What plug configuration do you have? I would think it should be a NEMA 6-20, two hots, and a ground, no neutral. If you have 4 wires going to the panel from the junction box just connect green/bare to receptacle (and box if metal). The white wire can be connected in the panel, just put a wirenut on the white in the j-box to insulate against inadvertent contact.
